# Problema com Desenvolvimento em Unity 3D

Tags: unity3d

Estou criando um projeto de um game em Unity 5-64bits, estou na parte de criação da movimentação da câmera. Quando eu estava digitando o código Javascript, ao tentar utilizar parênteses sempre dava o seguinte erro:

> An error has occurred - error in text editor extension chair

---

[image: Erro da utilização de parênteses]

---

Relevei o erro e continuei a terminar o código, cheguei em um ponto que já dava pra executar, mas ao arrastar o código para o local da a seguinte mensagem:

> Please Fix compile erros before creating new script components

Meu código:

```
#pragma strict

var Velocidade: Vector3;

function Start () {
}

function Update () {

   Velocidade.x =0;
   Velocidade.y =0;
   Velocidade.z =0;

   if (Input.mousePosition.x<=5 || Input.mousePosition.x>=screen.width-5)
   {
      Velocidade.x = Input.GetAxis ("Mouse X")*10*Time.deltaTime;
   }

   if (Input.mousePosition.y<=5 || input.mousePosition.y>=screen.height-5)
   {
      Velocidade.z = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X")*10*Time.deltaTime;
   }

   transform.Translate(Velocidade);
}
```

E ao clicar *Play* aparece a seguinte mensagem:

> All compiler errors have to be fixed before you can enter playmode!

Creio eu que ela seja por conta dos problemas...

Comment: Pode mostrar os _Details_ dessa tela de erro do MonoDevelop?

Comment: Está aqui. 
http://pastebin.com/TwrV6CAd

Comment: Isso ai deve ser um erro do Monodevelop exclusivo da versão 64. Vi que algumas pessoas resolveram atualizando o Unity, outras desabilitando a linguagem `BOO` do Unity.

Answer (score 3):

Encontrei o erro!
Creio eu por ser alguma atualização do unity, que não executa o codigo não finalizado, ou por eu ter escrito o código errado.
quando eu conclui executou perfeitamente.

**Código finalizado.**

```js
#pragma strict

var Velocidade: Vector3;

var ConstanteZ: float;

var ConstanteX: float;

function Start () {

}

function Update () {



if (Input.mousePosition.x<=5 || Input.mousePosition.x>=Screen.width-5)
 {
   if (Input.GetAxis("Mouse X")!=0)
   {
   if (Input.GetAxis("Mouse X")>0 && Input.mousePosition.x>=Screen.width-5)
   {
    ConstanteX=2;
   } 
   else
   {
    if (Input.mousePosition.x<=5)
    {
      ConstanteX=-2;
     }
   }
  
    
    
    Velocidade.x = ConstanteX*30*Time.deltaTime;
   }
 }
 else
 {
 Velocidade.x=0;
 }

if (Input.mousePosition.y<=5 || Input.mousePosition.y>=Screen.height-5)
 {
  if (Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y")!=0)
   {
    if (Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y")>0 && Input.mousePosition.y>=Screen.height-5)
   {
    ConstanteZ=2;
   } 
   else
   {
    if (Input.mousePosition.y<=5)
    {
      ConstanteZ=-2;
     }
   }
  }
    Velocidade.z = ConstanteZ*30*Time.deltaTime;
   
 }
 else
 {
 Velocidade.z=0;
 }
 Velocidade.y = -Input.GetAxis("Mouse ScrollWheel")*200*Time.deltaTime ;
transform.Translate(Velocidade);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Parece que você está com este problema: ["Error in text editor extension chain." when trying to edit new UnityScript file](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/310829/error-in-text-editor-extension-chain-when-trying-t.html)

Resumindo, a configuração da extensão do Boo (add-in) está danificada.

Não tenho como confirmar no momento, os passos sugeridos no link.
Então não posso afirmar exatamente o que você deve deletar.

Possivelmente, **desabilitando** o **Boo** no **Add-in Manager**, na seção Language Bindings. Fechando o Unity e o MonoDevelop, e abrindo novamente o Unity, é o suficiente.

Comment: Pode ser mais especifico em relação ao que devo fazer!? pois não compreendi nada.

Comment: Desabilite o plug-in do Boo. Algo como: [link1](http://www.jakel168.com/2015/01/bookmark-solving-monodevelop-editor.html) ou [link2](http://fernmac.blogspot.com.br/2012/04/where-is-add-in-manager-in-mono-mac-or.html)